# UITableview from scratch

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a `UITableView` which I need to add text and image - simple. 
The text comes from one table in a database and the image comes from another table. These tables are linked with an ID column.

The text comes in from a SQL command block and also it brings in the ID. The ID is then queried with a Custom API and that brings back the URL for the image.

Now after so much trouble with this. I have written it very simple. Here goes

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    ImageURL = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"http://calcuttans.com/palki/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/kidscover-small.png",@"http://outtonightapp.com/uploads/wether2.jpg",@"http://outtonightapp.com/uploads/wether3.jpg",nil];
    notification = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"wow",@"shit",@"tito", nil];  
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [notification count];
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"cell"];

    // putting text in rows by indexpath.row
    cell.textLabel.text = notification[indexPath.row];

    // putting an image on a row

    switch (indexPath.row) {
        case 0:
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[ImageURL objectAtIndex:(0)]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];
            break;
        case 1:
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[ImageURL objectAtIndex:(1)]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];
            break;
        case 2:
            [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[ImageURL objectAtIndex:(2)]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];
            break;
    }
    return cell;
}

@end
```

Now I need to remove the arrays and get the data from SQL and put in arrays but when I have done this in the past they have not come in because of the program flow. So how best would it be to get these in an array. Should I create an `.h` and `.m` file for text and one for image and then run them from `viewDidLoad`. I don't want to be in the position where I have all the data and again it is not showing in the tableview. At the moment this code works!

thanks

jason

Comment: `[cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[ImageURL objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]] placeholderImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"greybox40.png"]];` ?

Comment: you should probably have the data(array) ready before you come to this view controller or in viewDidLoad you can query for the data. What I would suggest is you create a class(say Data.h & Data.m) that has text and image details. your array should be containing objects of this custom class

Answer (score 0):

on app start in `[view didLoad]` show some activity indicator, while data is loading, 
in moment when you get all data in `notification` array call `[_yourTableViewName reloadData];` and stop activity indicator

Comment: I understand that, so the data can be loaded in a different thread, while the UI thread is being held until the data is loaded ? Any idea of an activity indicator I could use and if POSSIBLE some quick code sample.

Comment: all network requests is asynchronous for default, don't worry about this. Or better you can use AFNetwork that help with all this kitchen.  About activity indicator I mean `UIActivityIndicatorView`

Comment: right so I use UIActivityIndicatorView to block the UI. get all the details from the arrays and then use [reload data] ?

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion you don't really want to 'remove the array'...

A tableView is, essentially, a ui device for representing an array, or in the case of a grouped table, an array of arrays.  Each cell ought represent a member in an array so that what's on the screen matches the data model.  In your example here I would be looking at an nsarray of NSDictionaries, each having matching keys for objects like NSStrings and images etc or an array of objects of your own custom class which has properties you can set with data as you retrieve it, image file names, strings etc.  the model should always match what's being drawn on the screen

Answer (score 0):

> The text comes in from a SQL command block and also it brings in the
>   ID.

So form a `dictionary` as ID as key and text as the value. Return the count of dictionary in `numberOfRowsInSection` and in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, create the url from ID and query the image.

For example your dict may have following structure:

```
{
   "1" : "wow",
   "2" : "shit"
}
```

Now return the count of dictionary in `numberOfRowsInSection` as

```
return [dict count];
```

Now in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`, get the id

```
NSString *id= [[actorsDictionary allKeys] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
//Create your custom api based on id and call to get image
//Note: You can try out AsyncImageView if you want
```

This is just another way of doing your requirement. Hope it helps.